# Failed to instantiate RedisTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have a Spring Boot Application with Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.1.0, I am trying to connect my application with redis server but when I try to run the application it throws an exception as

```
aused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception with message: org.springframework.data.convert.EntityInstantiators
```

My Config class is as

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Did I miss anything?
Thank you!